# Ranking based on a dynamic table - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, ranking

I have created a table in my report with field parameters to allow the user to filter columns manually.

The field parameter looks like this:

```
Select column = {
    ("Column 1", NAMEOF('Participation'[A]), 2),
    ("Column 2", NAMEOF('Participation'[B]), 3),
    ("Column 3", NAMEOF('Participation'[C]), 4),
    ("Column 4", NAMEOF('Participation'[D]), 5),
...
}
```

The table will look like this, where the "Round" is static based on a calendar table and the other columns are based on the field parameter.

| Round | A | B | C | D | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| September 22 | 75 % | x % | x % | x % |  |
| October 23 | 80 % | x % | x % | x % |  |
| November 23 | 90 % | x % | x % | x % |  |
| ... | x % | x % | x % | x % |  |

Finally, I want to show the top 3 participation rates per column. For example, I select column A using the button, I want to display in a chart:

1. 90%  November 23
2. 80% October 23
3. 75% September 22

The ranking based on one column is easy, but I have big problems to show it dynamically. Most of the solutions on the web where it is explained for dynamic tables are not based on field parameters.

I already tried it like this:

```
Ranking Team = 
VAR SelectedColumn = SELECTEDVALUE('Select column'[Select column Felder])
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        SelectedColumn,
        "A", RANKX(ALL('Participation'), [A], , DESC),
        "B", RANKX(ALL('Participation'), [B], , DESC),
        "C", RANKX(ALL('Participation'), [C], , DESC),
        "D", RANKX(ALL('Participation'), [D], , DESC),
        "E", RANKX(ALL('Participation'), [E], , DESC),
        "F", RANKX(ALL('Participation'), [F], , DESC),
        "G", RANKX(ALL('Participation'), [G], , DESC),
        "H", RANKX(ALL('Participation'), [H], , DESC),
        BLANK()
    )
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I think the problem is that this DAX is not based on my field parameter table.

Tanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're trying to dynamically rank a column based on user selection, but DAX doesn't allow for direct dynamic column referencing based on string names. So, even if your SWITCH statement is perfectly fine, you won't be able to change the column you're using in the RANKX function on-the-fly.

First, make sure the field parameter is returning the exact column names (like 'A', 'B', 'C'...) that you are using in the SWITCH statement.

Then use a measure to fetch the column values based on the selected value dynamically:

```
Selected Participation Value = 
VAR SelectedColumn = SELECTEDVALUE('Select column'[Select column Felder])
RETURN 
SWITCH(
    SelectedColumn,
    "A", 'Participation'[A],
    "B", 'Participation'[B],
    "C", 'Participation'[C],
    "D", 'Participation'[D],
    BLANK()
)
```

Then, create a ranking measure using the above measure:

```
Ranking Team = 
RANKX(ALL('Participation'), [Selected Participation Value], , DESC)
```

Keep in mind, you need to know all the columns beforehand to set up the SWITCH statement. It won't be suitable if you have a dynamic set of columns that can change often.